# My guess for the zero ideal in F[x], where $F$ is a field.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory, maximal-and-prime-ideals, polynomial-rings

I know proposition 7 in Dummit & Foote that says "Every nonzero prime ideal in PID is a maximal ideal"  and I know that $F(x)$ is a PID.

But I was asked to show that: Every prime ideal of $F[x]$ is a maximal ideal of $F[x].$

My guess is that the question is asking me this(Every prime ideal and not every **non zero** prime ideal) because the zero ideal in $F[x]$ is just generated by zero so it comes from the zero polynomial which lies in $F$(any field is an integral domain and the zero ideal in an integral domain is a prime ideal) and in a field the zero ideal is always a maximal ideal, is my guess correct?

Comment: @coffeemath I am sorry, I did not get how your comment answers my question, but I edited my question as I felt that it may be unclear.

Comment: What is the precise definition of "prime ideal" you are using?

Comment: Yes, obviously "every *nonzero* prime ideal is maximal" is intended. PIDs are precisely the UFDs satisfying this property (i.e. having Krull dimension at most $1).\,$ See the linked dupe for more.

Comment: @BillDubuque my question was why incase of polynomials in one indeterminate over a field the question said every prime ideal not every **nonzero** prime ideal and if my guess is correct or no

Comment: It's a typo/braino (inconsistent with the prior more general Prop. 7 you quote). It is incorrect without "nonzero".

Comment: @BillDubuque so my justification for the zero prime ideal in this case was wrong also?

Comment: What you wrote is correct but it is not clear why you think this can justify said false claim. $(0)$ is prime in $F[x]$ but not maximal so that is a counterexample to what you were asked to show.

Comment: Because the question was from a previous exam year so I was pretending that I am in the exam and that this will be my answer if I met this question @BillDubuque ....... also, if the statement is still correct then nothing is wrong with the exam question ...... right(the zero prime ideal is still a maximal ideal in this case and I think that is why the examiner did not put the word nonzero)?

Comment: The statement is *not* correct since my prior comment gives a counterexample.  In one place you mention the *field* $F(x)$. Is that what you mean elsewhere (vs. $F[x]$?). Note $(0)$ is maximal in $R\iff R$ is a field, but $F[x]$ is not a field.

Comment: My bad, in all of my writings,  I only meant either $F$ or $F[x]$ ...... I did not mean to write $F(x)$ at all. @BillDubuque

Comment: @coffeemath I am using that a proper ideal $P$ of a commutative ring A with identity is prime iff when $ab \in P$ then either $a\in P$ or $b \in P$?

Comment: @Emptymind Then see Bill's comments above.